# If Statement to check Excel column for a match value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use an `If statement` (`VBA` code) to check the cell range in a column for a given numeric parameter. For the cell that matches the given value, the cells at the right (in the same row) should change the background color.

Pseudocode Example:

```
A1=5,7  
If cell in Range(F1:F10) has value=A1 Then  
(random matched cell: F7=5,7)  
Range (G7:M7) = Background Blue
```

The part to change the background I know how to do it, but what is the best way to check the given range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
for i = 1 to 10 'rows in column f to loop through
  if cells(i,6) = cells(1,1) then 'column a is 1, column f is 6, etc.
    range(cells(i,7), cells(i,13)).interior.colorindex = 'number for that color
  end if
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may have multiple rows in F1:F10 that have a match on A1. I would iterate through the cells in the range with:

```
For each rngCell in Range("F1:F10")
     If rngCell.value = Range("A1").value
          Range("G" & rngCell.row, "M" & rngCell.row).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
     End If
Next
```